# Why is the gram no longer a function of the atomic mass number?

Tags: nomenclature

According to Wikipedia,

> ... the definition of the gram is not (as of 2011) mathematically tied to that of the atomic mass unit

Why did we change that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the question, the gram was never defined that way.

For historical reasons the SI unit for mass is an oddity:

1. The base unit is not the gram, but the kilogram. This is the only case where the base unit has a prefix. The gram is defined as $\frac{1}{1000}$ of a kilogram.
2. The kilogram is the only remaining SI unit that is based on a man-made object, the [International Prototype of the Kilogram](http://www.bipm.org/en/bipm/mass/prototype.html).

At its 25th meeting in 2014, the General Conference on Weights and Measures (CGPM) has (again) declared its intention to abandon this atificial standard and link

> the definitions of the kilogram, ampere, kelvin, and mole to exact numerical values of the
>   Planck constant $h$, elementary charge $e$, Boltzmann constant *k*, and Avogadro constant $N_A$ […]

([Source](http://www.bipm.org/en/CGPM/db/25/1/))

One of the possible approaches for the redefinition of the kilogram would be a side-effect of the redefinition of the Avogadro constant with in the [Avogadro project](http://www.ptb.de/cms/en/presseaktuelles/journals-magazines/ptb-news/ptb-news-ausgaben/ptb-news/news05-3/avogadro-project-first-isotope-pure-silicon-single-crystal.html).

Comment: The [decision on the redefinition](https://www.bipm.org/en/news/full-stories/2018-11-si-overhaul.html) was made in 2018 and will be in effect May 20th 2019.